# Access button to open multiple reports depending on user input

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to access so this might be an easy task or I am just trying to tackle it wrongly. I have a report that has various columns, sample id, sample time, sample type, dry matter, moisture. I am trying to create a button that has an input box for the user to chose what column to sort the report by. So far I thought of creating various reports that have been sorted by each column, named the reports by the column that sorts them then I am trying to have the open report action have a parameter that opens the report linked to the column entered at the input box. Is this even possible or is there a workaround for this.

PS. I am avoiding creating various buttons since it will fill up the screen.

Comment: reports have an ```.orderby``` property, use that to sort. You can get a parameter to have a title label change by creating a sub routine in a module set a global variable and then in the ```report_load``` event assign that variable to the labels ```.value``` property.

Comment: I will give this a shot and let you know if it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Warcupine, you have an example of a code I can reference? I have no idea how to write create a global variable and If I am referencing the querries or the reports and where to add the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is pretty generic and will require some tweaking but it shows the core of how to do this.

To start with you need a module (so not form/report code). This is where the globals will be assigned values:

[image]

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Global rptname As String
Global fldname As String

Sub setRptName(name As String)
    
    rptname = "Report Sorted by: " & name
    fldname = name
End Sub
```

You will call that code inside the `Click()` event of your command button on your form and then open the report after that. This will take a combo box value and pass that value to the module code, creating the two global variables.:

[image]

```
Private Sub cmd_report_Click()
    mdl_Globals.setRptName Me.cmb_fields.Value
    
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Report1", acViewPreview
End Sub
```

[image]

I'm unsure if this will work with non-preview views, but you probably want preview anyway.

Lastly in the report code behind, you need the `Load()` and `open()` events, you may be able to get it to work with both inside one or other but I know this one works.
So to set the caption:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Me.lbl_header.Caption = rptname
End Sub
```

And then to sort:

```
Private Sub report_open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Report.OrderBy = "[" & fldname & "]"
    Me.Report.OrderByOn = True
End Sub
```

[image]

If your entry box on the form does not have entries that exactly match the name(s) of the fields in the table you will get a parameter popup.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not grasping the concept but I am trying to figure out where I put in the report name and pretty much tuning the code to fit my DB. My report name is rptdrymatter where should I add the report name in the code?

Comment: To open the report or add that to a label in the report?

Comment: both. LIke from your code which step should I add the report name?

Comment: Or pretty much I can rephrase my question, can you explain what is happening in the code and how the user will be prompted to add a column in a prompt box to sort the report

Comment: So you have your table with all the data, you create a combo box in a form where the options you can choose are the fields in the table. Once a value is selected you press a button, this button then calls code located in a module. The module code assigns values to global variables based on the selection in the combo box. After the module code runs the button then opens the report, the report looks at those global variables to change the title label caption and sort order.

Comment: I am having a hard time getting the module code correct. I created the combo box with the drop down being the field headers. Now the module code is just not working. Is it possible for you to break it down code by code with an example of codes using my naming sequence.

Comment: The first two code in boxes on your response, are htey all going to be in the on click command and where did you assign the global variables?

Comment: I'll try to break it down, I don't know the names of your controls / reports / forms etc so I can't really replace the generic ones with yours. In the first two code blocks: 1) is in a module (in the project explorer insert new module) 2) is in the code behind of the form containing the combobox and command button.

Comment: Here is my VBA code,       

Private Sub Command271_Click()
Option Compare Database

Global rptname As String
Global fldname As String


Option Explicit
    
        
Sub setrptname(name As String)

    rptname = "Report Sorted by:" & name
    fldname = name
    
End Sub

Private Sub
    
    mdl_Globals.setrptname Me.cmb_fields.Value
    
    DoCmd.OpenReport "DryMatterGrowr-R_Cutter", acViewPreview
End Sub

Private Sub Report_Load()
    Me.lbl_header.Caption = rptname
End Sub

Comment: Private Sub report_open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Report.OrderBy = "[" & fldname & "]"
    Me.Report.OrderByOn = True
End Sub


End Sub
I am getting a compile error on the: Option compare database line.

Comment: Option Compare and Option Explicit go at the top above the sub declaration, the global declarations also go above the sub, they cannot be located inside of it.

Comment: Private Sub Report_Load()
    Me.lbl_header.Caption = rptname
End Sub

What does lbl_header reference?

Comment: A label on the report.

Comment: I am getting a runtime error '424' 
Object required

Comment: This is happening on the click VBA

Private Sub Command271_Click()
    mdl_Globals.setRptName Me.cmb_fields.Value --- ERROR ON THIS LINE
    
    DoCmd.OpenReport "DryMatterGrowr-R_Cutter", acViewPreview
End Sub

Comment: I think I have not referenced my globals correctly. should I name the module mdl_Globals

Comment: Yeah, the module should have that name and the ```_Click()``` event should be in the form's code behind.

Comment: Ok I fixed that, now I am getting another error on teh report open. 

Compile error: Ambiguous name detected: fldname

Comment: This is happening on the 

Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Report_Load()
    Me.lbl_header.Caption = rptname
End Sub

Private Sub report_open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Report.OrderBy = "[" & fldname & "]" ----HAPPENING RIGHT HERE
    Me.Report.OrderByOn = True
End Sub

Comment: You have two ```fldname``` variables one in ```mdl_Globals``` and one somewhere else that is in scope, if it's not in the ```Report_Load()``` sub then it is declared as a global twice somewhere.

Comment: Yeah i created a second mdl_Globals so i deleted the second one but now i have another error.

Compile error:
Method or data member not found. 

This is happening on the:

Private Sub Report_Load()
    Me.lbl_header.Caption = rptname --- the lbl_header
End Sub

Comment: What exactly is the lbl_header referencing? Do I have it named differently and I am trying to call lbl_header and yet it is something else?

Comment: It is referencing a label control with the name lbl_header on the report

Comment: One more question. The table I created to populate the combo box was a simple table with the column headers as the data in the table and not the actual table that needs to populate the report. Is that correct? Because with the actual table I was getting a whole column of the table in the dropdown but with the simple table I just have the column headers as the options to choose from.

Comment: Another issue is one column header works for the sort in the report but when I pick another column it acts as a parameter and prompts me to enter something on a text box. Do you have an idea of what might be causing that?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way to do it, you could also hardcode the names in and not have it table linked, or a bit of vba in the form that loads the field names into the combobox. You probably have a slight misspelling that's causing the parameter pop up

Comment: It was a spelling error on the name. it works perfectly!

Comment: Hi, do you have a clue of where needs to be changed, and what needs to be added to make the report open a nonsorted report without choosing a column from the dropdown? Now it just pops an error; invalid use of null.

Comment: You need an ```if``` statement in the ```report_open``` module on the report code behind and possibly on the form when getting the value from the box. You may need to do ```isnull()``` but can probably just check for an empty string. If it's empty don't sort.

Comment: If i want to filter the report and not order by the value do i just change the :  Me.Report.OrderBy = "[" & fldname & "]"
    Me.Report.OrderByOn = True

Comment: @Godwill I would check to see if ```fldname``` is an empty string if it is then do nothing else sort. That way users can switch between them as they see fit.

Comment: I want to use the Frisian to filter the report query

Comment: I want to use the value of the combo box to filter the report query

Comment: Filtering is a bit different from sorting, ```docmd.openreport``` has a [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openreport) for that.